# How can I perform an action with touchesEnded from my custom button subclass in my SpriteKit scene?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have created my own SKNode subclass in order to create a button class. I got it to show the button but couldn’t get it to work. By now I have made a method in my class to get the action I want the button to do as it is touched. But actually I don’t know how to pass that action as I override touchesEnded() in my class. I’ve tried almost everything I could find with no result.
My code:

```
override init() {
  super.init()
  self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
var actionTouchUpInside: Selector?
var actionTouchUp: Selector?
var actionTouchDown: Selector?
weak var targetTouchUpInside: AnyObject?
weak var targetTouchUp: AnyObject?
weak var targetTouchDown: AnyObject?

func setButtonAction(target: AnyObject, triggerEvent event:SKButtonActionType, action:Selector) {

    switch (event) {
    case .TouchUpInside:
      targetTouchUpInside = target
      actionTouchUpInside = action
    case .TouchDown:
      targetTouchDown = target
      actionTouchDown = action
    case .TouchUp:
      targetTouchUp = target
      actionTouchUp = action
    }
}
override public func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
     if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.location(in: parent!)
        if self.contains(location) {
        // Code for performing the action
         }
     }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: do you have .isUserInteractionEnabled = true set on your custom class?

Comment: Of Course it is, in init()

Comment: Don't say "Of Course it is" like it should be obvious! it wasn't obvious and you don't show that in your code! best of luck with your question

Comment: I selected the part I had trouble with in order to improve readability. I apologise. If you consider there is anything else I should include concerning my issue, please tell me.

Comment: Most of the code I didn’t post was about displaying the button and the class declaration

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My code was right, my trouble was on a function that I had defined as an objective-C function when trying to use the button class. If it is useful for someone where it is written:
// Code for performing the action
you should, actually write there the code to perform.

Comment: You just need to use @objc to make your swift functions visible to obj c

Comment: That’s it. I had some functions that needed to be presented to obj-c so I accidentally wrote an obj-c function instead of a normal function.